# Algorithmicx - caption alignment of 2-column sub-algorithms of different height

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, boxes, subcaption, algorithmicx

I have 2 sub-algorithms that need to be placed side-by-side (2 columns) using the `algpseduocode` layout from the `algorithmicx` package.  Since I need to refer to each of them individually in the following text paragraphs whilst also having a common caption, I chose the `subfigure` environment provided by the `subcaption` package.

The problem is that, while I'd like the (content of the) algorithms themselves to be vertically aligned centrally, I need their individual captions to also line up. But presently I do not know how to do it. The figure illustrates the current alignment and the requirement position of the caption.

[image: mis-aligned alog figure]

Here is the `MWE` to produce this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \fbox{
        \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.50\textwidth}
            \begin{algorithmic}[0]
                \Procedure{Main}{}
                    \State configure interrupts
                    \State enable timers
                    \State $\vdots$
                    \While{\textproc{True}} \Comment{until shutdown}
                        \State background task \#1 \Comment{safety checks}
                        \State background task \#2
                        \State $\vdots$
                        \If{Calibrate}
                            \Function{doCalibration}{$x$}
                                \State subroutine for calibration
                                \State $\vdots$
                            \EndFunction
                        \EndIf
                        \State $\vdots$
                        \State background task \#$n$ \Comment{serial comm.}
                    \EndWhile
                \EndProcedure
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{background processes}
            \label{subfig:bgRTprocess}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.47\textwidth}
            % \centering
            \raggedright
            \begin{algorithmic}[0]
                \Function{ISR}{$ $}
                    \State read sensor data from ADC
                    \State $\vdots$
                    \State initialise model
                    \Function{computeControl}{$x$}
                        \State evalute modeleqns
                        \State $\vdots$
                    \EndFunction
                    \State $\vdots$
                    \State write control output to DAC
                    \vfill
                \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{foreground process}
            \label{subfig:fgRTprocess}
        \end{subfigure}
    }
    \caption{RT software architecture of a microcontroller}
    \label{fig:basicRTCsoftwarearch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this desired placement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity of a solution, I'd suggest raising the right-hand algorithm into position by adding something like `\vspace{3.75\baselineskip}` after the `algorithmic` environment and using a `[b]`ottom alignment for the `subfigure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Procedure{Main}{}
          \State configure interrupts
          \State enable timers
          \State $\vdots$
          \While{\textproc{True}} \Comment{until shutdown}
            \State background task \#1 \Comment{safety checks}
            \State background task \#2
            \State $\vdots$
            \If{Calibrate}
              \Function{doCalibration}{$x$}
                \State subroutine for calibration
                \State $\vdots$
              \EndFunction
            \EndIf
            \State $\vdots$
            \State background task \#$n$ \Comment{serial comm.}
          \EndWhile
        \EndProcedure
      \end{algorithmic}
      \caption{background processes}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Function{ISR}{$ $}
          \State read sensor data from ADC
          \State $\vdots$
          \State initialise model
          \Function{computeControl}{$x$}
            \State evalute modeleqns
            \State $\vdots$
          \EndFunction
          \State $\vdots$
          \State write control output to DAC
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
      \vspace{3.75\baselineskip}
      \caption{foreground process}
    \end{subfigure}
  }
  \caption{RT software architecture of a microcontroller}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An alternative (for perfect vertical alignment) would be to place the larger content in a box that one can measure and then move the smaller box into position by half of the difference. The end result would be only a marginal improvement on the vertical alignment.

---

Here is the alternative method - storing each algorithm in a box that can be measured. That way you can move the smaller one into position:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\algboxA}
\newsavebox{\algboxB}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \savebox{\algboxA}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Procedure{Main}{}
          \State configure interrupts
          \State enable timers
          \State $\vdots$
          \While{\textproc{True}} \Comment{until shutdown}
            \State background task \#1 \Comment{safety checks}
            \State background task \#2
            \State $\vdots$
            \If{Calibrate}
              \Function{doCalibration}{$x$}
                \State subroutine for calibration
                \State $\vdots$
              \EndFunction
            \EndIf
            \State $\vdots$
            \State background task \#$n$ \Comment{serial comm.}
          \EndWhile
        \EndProcedure
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \savebox{\algboxB}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Function{ISR}{$ $}
          \State read sensor data from ADC
          \State $\vdots$
          \State initialise model
          \Function{computeControl}{$x$}
            \State evalute modeleqns
            \State $\vdots$
          \EndFunction
          \State $\vdots$
          \State write control output to DAC
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }

  \fbox{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
      \usebox{\algboxA}
      \caption{background processes}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
      \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\algboxA-.5\ht\algboxB}{%
        \usebox{\algboxB}%
      }
      \caption{foreground process}
    \end{subfigure}
  }
  \caption{RT software architecture of a microcontroller}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not want to hand-compute the lengths such as ```3.75``` to achieve vertical centering.  I need to typeset more specific statements within the procedure and functions that any manually set-up height shall immediately change. Is there a way for latex to calculate the required height for centered vertical alignment automatically. I am using ```LuaTex```. Does having lua interpreter help in any way for such computations?

Comment: @Krishna: I've added an update to the answer: Storing the algorithms in boxes which can be measured. That way you can move them around as needed.