# Bounding boxes for each column of a 2-column algorithm & align them flush with page margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, subcaption, algorithmicx, bounding-box

I have two sub-algorithms for side-by-side placement using the `algpseudocode` layout from the `algorithmicx` package.  Since each sub-algorithm needs to be individually referred in text, I chose the `subfigure` environment provided by the `subcaption` package. Thanks to the community's [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432387/algorithmicx-caption-alignment-of-2-column-sub-algorithms-of-different-height/432404), I have made a good start.

However, the two sub-algorithms are typeset too closely to visually distinguish them. Furthermore, there is excessive white space to the right of the RHS algorithm .

The figure below describes the issue.

[image: bad horizontal alignment of sub-algorithms]

It is produced by the following `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\algboxA}
\newsavebox{\algboxB}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \savebox{\algboxA}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Procedure{Main}{}
          \State configure interrupts
          \State enable timers
          \State $\vdots$
          \While{\textproc{True}} \Comment{until shutdown}
            \State background task \#1 \Comment{safety checks}
            \State background task \#2
            \State $\vdots$
            \If{Calibrate}
              \Function{doCalibration}{$x$}
                \State subroutine for calibration
                \State $\vdots$
              \EndFunction
            \EndIf
            \State $\vdots$
            \State background task \#$n$ \Comment{serial comm.}
          \EndWhile
        \EndProcedure
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \savebox{\algboxB}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Function{ISR}{$ $}
          \State read sensor data from ADC
          \State $\vdots$
          \State initialise model
          \Function{computeControl}{$x$}
            \State evalute modeleqns
            \State $\vdots$
          \EndFunction
          \State $\vdots$
          \State write control output to DAC
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }

  \fbox{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
      \usebox{\algboxA}
      \caption{background processes}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
      \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\algboxA-.5\ht\algboxB}{%
        \usebox{\algboxB}%
      }
      \caption{foreground process}
    \end{subfigure}
  }
  \caption{RT software architecture of a microcontroller}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The annotations describe a proposed fix, i.e. flush the respectively sub-algorithms within their minipages/parboxes. This **did not** work for me and even if it did, I am afraid this could be sub-optimal.

There could be other better fixes -- perhaps instead of hard-coding each subfigure to `0.48` of `\textwidth` , maybe it is possible to dynamically calculate the optimal container size of each sub-algorithm and place them flush with their respective margins.

Any help on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman yes. Already tried. Does not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. The right `minipage` is to wide for it's contents, leaving a lot of space on the right. This can be fixed by reducing the width of both, the `minipage` and the right `subfigure`.
2. The `\fbox` adapts its width automatically to the contents. Thus, the `\hfill` between the `subfigure`s doesn't do anything. Replacing `\fbox` by `\framebox[\textwidth]` fixes this.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{algorithm} <-- doesn't exist
\usepackage{algorithmicx} % used this instead
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\algboxA}
\newsavebox{\algboxB}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \savebox{\algboxA}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Procedure{Main}{}
          \State configure interrupts
          \State enable timers
          \State $\vdots$
          \While{\textproc{True}} \Comment{until shutdown}
            \State background task \#1 \Comment{safety checks}
            \State background task \#2
            \State $\vdots$
            \If{Calibrate}
              \Function{doCalibration}{$x$}
                \State subroutine for calibration
                \State $\vdots$
              \EndFunction
            \EndIf
            \State $\vdots$
            \State background task \#$n$ \Comment{serial comm.}
          \EndWhile
        \EndProcedure
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \savebox{\algboxB}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
      \begin{algorithmic}[0]
        \Function{ISR}{$ $}
          \State read sensor data from ADC
          \State $\vdots$
          \State initialise model
          \Function{computeControl}{$x$}
            \State evalute modeleqns
            \State $\vdots$
          \EndFunction
          \State $\vdots$
          \State write control output to DAC
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}%
  }

  \framebox[\textwidth]{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
      \usebox{\algboxA}
      \caption{background processes}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\algboxA-.5\ht\algboxB}{%
        \usebox{\algboxB}%
      }
      \caption{foreground process}
    \end{subfigure}
  }
  \caption{RT software architecture of a microcontroller}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```